# Fields not shows in the page while using custom content type in drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7

Hi anybody help me as soon as possible.
I am creating a custom content type in Drupal 7 & added some field but it not shows in the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to make it visible at the content type's editing page, at the display options section. 
The correct URL is:

/admin/structure/types/manage/{custom_content_type_name}/display

Change {custom_content_type_name} to the respective name.